# Resolving jquery conflicts - tablesorter and star rating

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, jquery-plugins

In my jsp i have included both tablesorter and jquery star rating plugins. There seems to be some jquery conflicts. I will explain the problem step by step
If am including these files :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "js/jquery.rating.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
```

Then intially both star rating and tablesorter are working perfectly. But after ajax call tablesorter is giving error "TypeError: table.config.parsers[c] is undefined"

Case II:
if i am including these files

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "js/jquery.rating.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
```

Then initally both tablesorter and star rating is working fine. But after ajax call star rating is not working. Can anyone help please in resolving these conflicts :(

Comment: You're including tablesorter twice - remove the non min version

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Still the same issue Sir  :(

Comment: I removed the non-min version of tablesorter. Sill after ajax call same issue is coming. Please help sir :(